# Generating vcxproj files with object output paths like in object_parallel_to_source mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt5, qmake

What configuration do I need to give QMake to generate a vcxproj file where the object files are arranged in a tree like the original code?

I have been searching for quite a while and even scrutinized the source of qmake but to no avail.

So far I tried `CONFIG -= flat` which only changed the filters, but not the output paths. And object_parallel_to_source which only works with makefiles as far as I can tell.

I need the feature to avoid name clashes of object files having the same name, because their source files have the same name but reside in different folders.

It is definitely possible to avoid this with MSVC by setting the appropriate output path for files in their properties dialog. However, this is tedious and as I am developing a project mainly on Linux and then porting it over to Windows from time to time I have to do the whole procedure over and over again.